# Boolean cuts on one side but adds to the other

Tags: modifiers, error

[image][image]
[image]

I had one boolean perfectly cut in this model but the one in the pictures below has an error of some sort. Has anyone had an error like this? How do i solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is correct, this is how the Boolean modifier works.

The Boolean modifier works better with manifold meshes (which, looking at your pictures, your mesh is not). If the mesh is not manifold, it does some guesswork which is inconsistent sometimes. I would recommend making your mesh manifold first by completing it.

If you wish to create a cut and not an incision, duplicate the front faces of the object you used to cut the model, separate it from the cutting object to make a new object, select both the new object and the object to be cut into, go into Edit Mode, hit A  to select all faces of both objects, and go to Mesh > Knife Project.

You should now have a hole without the supporting geometry.

Comment: But in the same model, i have a boolean that worked well. It ´s odd that one works and the other doesn´t.

Comment: @JoãoMamede Can you add pictures of that correct hole to your post?

Comment: @JoãoMamede I tried to reproduce this issue with a plane, but I could not. Could you share the .blend file in your post?

Comment: see the picture pls

Answer (score 0):

Try using "**Union**". It solved the problem for me.

*(First two images are using "Difference", the last one is using "Union")*

[image: The modifier with the "Union" option selected.]
[image: USING "DIFFERENCE"]
[image: USING "DIFFERENCE"]
[image: USING "UNION"]